# FaceTime iPhone

Tags: iphone

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

In the above code "123456789" is a inbuilt iPhone no or our own phone number?

Thanks,
Vadivel

Comment: 19 questions and a 0% answer rate? Jeez...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the phone number that you want call.